# How to format a drive with Nodejs without child_proccess

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, format, drive

How do I format a drive (aka usb stick/external hdd) with Nodejs without having to use cli/cmd/child_proccess?

I'm creating a small tool with nodejs that needs to clear a hdd before adding some files onto it, but I can't find any library that allows me asynchronous (or synchronous for that matter) access to those tools.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a Node module which will provide drive formatting, so the only solution I can think of is to use the `fs` module to traverse the drive and remove (using `fs.unlink` for files and `fs.rmdir` for directories) its contents manually.

Comment: I was afraid of that ;_;    Thanks for the option!

Comment: what's wrong with child_process?

Comment: If I just invoke the cmd (it's for Windows) via child_process, and pass it the operands to preform the format I won't get (as far as I can find) feedback as to when the operation has completed. (Feel free to prove me wrong, I'd love to find out that there's a way to get async feedback from cmd via child_process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `child_process` and writing a library that lets you set responders for certain outputs semantically similar to [`node-suppose`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-suppose) by `jprichardson`, Called [`respond`](https://github.com/schme16/node-respond)
(Can be installed by npm install respond - Documentation here: https://github.com/schme16/node-respond/blob/master/README.md)